# Can I use combination with spinning/locked column, nested header and grouping row together with MUI-X?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

I am very interesting in buying the mui-x pro license cuz I found mui-x has locked column, nested headers and grouping row feature in its docs. However, there is not any example to show the combination of all three features together. Has anybody tried this?

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN2Yg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried these in the playground of mui-x by myself.

The answer is yes, mui-x does support such combination.

[image]